# In Angular (ng2) is there a difference in the import statements when you leave a space after the curly bracket?

Tags: angular

I have seen some people importing like this:

```
{ Component }
```

and some people importing stuff like this:

```
{Component}
```

Is there a difference?

Comment: No, it is literally just stylistic preference. This also has nothing to do with Angular 2. This is a matter of JavaScript style.

Comment: The white space is ignored. No difference.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything. Still learning.